# What is the difference between adding <?> to the argument and not adding it?

Tags: java, generics

Lets say I have the class :

```
class Box<T>{}
```

Now what is the difference between :

```
public myMethod(Box box){};
```

and

```
public myMethod(Box<?> box){};
```

**Update:**

I'm asking because I want to see the effect on the variable `box`, Is the variable identical in both cases or not.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Those docs do not answer his question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: I think this question is about raw types, not the wildcard as super to all types concept.

Comment: I updated the question. Its not about when should I use the raw type, its about if there any effect on the parameter if I want to use it inside the method (is the two objects will be identical or did they have different informations about their type)

Answer (score 3):

> `Collection<?>` (pronounced "collection of unknown"), that is, a
>   collection whose element type matches anything.

I am not sure about your Box class definition so it is hard to describe it from that. But if you use any collection such as List, Map, Set. Then you can define the type of objects it may contain using generics. So if the type is not defined then it means you are allowing the raw types in your colection as mentioned here

```
Collection c;
```

But if you want this collection to store only a particular type then you can specify it using generfic. For examlple a collection of String:

```
Collection<String> c;
```

But if you want to allow any type of object to be stored then you use collection of unknown, as defined here:

```
Collection<?> c;
```

Using generics, allow you to find problems during compile time.

Read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: This doesn't explain what plain `Box` means, or the difference between it and `Box<?>`.

Comment: See update, I'm more concern about the effect on the parameter inside the method.

Comment: @Jimmy There is actually no difference because in both the cases you are allowing any type of elements in your Box collection.

Comment: @Jimmy There is a difference. A `Box<?>` will not accept any input except `null`, since it's type is unknown (read about PECS). A `Box` will accept anything, and it's up to the caller to cast responsibly.

Comment: It bewilders me why 10k+ users decide to post lackluster answers instead of voting to close as duplicates of obvious and excellently answered posts - oh wait, points, nevermind.

Comment: @PaulBellora Not sure what you meant by *will not accept any input except null*, but if you try myMethod(new Box()) it will work for both cases.

Comment: @Jimmy I'm saying that if `Box` has a method `put(T item)`, then `put(someObject)` correctly won't compile with a `Box<?>`, because `someOject` can't be guaranteed to be the unknown type that `?` represents. Read about PECS.

Answer (score 3):

*Generics* have been introduced into Java to help you catch a wide range of bugs in compile-time, instead of just encountering `ClassCastException` at runtime.

When you use `<?>` (a *wildcard*) you are saying to the compiler that you don't know (or don't care about) the generic type. For example: if you just want to count the number of elements of an `Iterable<?>`, you simply don't care about the types of the elements, so you could create a method with the signature `int countElements(Iterable<?> iterable)`, that would simply retrieve an `Iterator<?>` from the `iterable` (note the wildcard type again), and then just call `hasNext()` and `next()`, while incrementing a counter.

You *could* do the same without the `<?>`, which is what is called a *raw type*.

You should almost never use *raw types*. Raw types are allowed since Java tries to be as backwards compatible as possible. If they didn't allow you to use raw types, almost all Java code from versions before 1.5 (when Generics have been introduced) would have to be rewritten; the raw types allows the compiler to compile that code -- although it will issue warnings.